# When I upload config file by curl tool it fails with curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 550

Tags: curl, tfs, tfsbuild, release

I have a step in my TFS release where I need to upload a config file.
I use curl to do that but I can not make to work it. curl always fails with the error curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 550. I check credentials and they are correct. What else can cause this issue ?

Comment: Does adding `-v` to the command line and view the commands/responses offer any more clues?

Comment: Thanks it works -V

Answer (score -1):

Adding -v solves the issue of curl: (25) Failed FTP upload: 550. Uload params are 
-Q \"+CWD site/wwwroot\" -v